# Why is my LC filter Bode flattening out to 20dB/dec in my Simscape simulation?

Tags: filter, matlab, resonance, bode-plot, simulink

I just made an LC filter Matlab Simulink simulation and I don’t know why the Bode diagram is flattening out.

After the resonance it falls steeply, but after that it sets at 20dB/decade. Shouldn't it be 40dB/decade?

It is a second order filter.
The inductance is 1.6uH and the capacitance is 330uF.

[image]

[image]

I checked at 150kHz the input and ouput signals. Accordin to my calculations it is -35dB. It is the samme on the Bode diagram

[image]
[image]

Comment: that isn't an LC filter. The is an L-LC filter and thus there is a 2nd assemptope

Comment: That is just the parasitic inductance of the capacitor. I get the same results without it.

Comment: While this is an old question, I think it can be explained with a little effort -- please add the resistor values used. In the mean time, voting to close for lack of information.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to plot the response of a circuit with simscape, the question is what method did you use

Using the bode block it can be seen above the natural frequency the rolloff is 40dB/decade.

There is a high chance that if you manually did a frequency sweep to a matlab workspace variable and then post-process the data, that you did not select a suitable sampling rate to reconstruct the data. Likewise the simscape reference block include a filter response as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!
How can the sampling rate be wrong? I put a sinudoidal voltage source on the input and I measured the amplitude on the output. I did is on many frequencies. It should give accurate results.

Comment: only if the sampling rate and the refinement factor is of suitable value

Comment: Could you explain it or recommend a place where I can learn about it, please?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/332630/bubba-oscillator-smooth-sine-curve-generation/332644#332644

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405189/matlab-three-phase-system-model/405200#405200

Comment: I don't think it is the problem. I used fixed-step solver with steps small enough even at high frequencies.

Comment: it will be a measurement issue as you MANUALLY "read" off at each frequency

Comment: I checked at 150kHz the input and ouput signals. Accordin to my calculations it is -35dB. It is the samme on the Bode diagram. I will attach 2 photos from the result of the simulation.